# GetFeature using BBOX and CQL filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, cql-filter

I want to get the data within BBOX and form the CQL query URL as following:

`http://[localhost]:8080/geoserver/mymap/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeatur
e&typeName=layer:layername&outputFormat=json&BBOX=-70.95699,50.89799,-71.17946,52.04493,EPSG:4326&cql_filter=(name+like+%27%25h%25%27%29`

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to combine the BBOX filter into the CQL filter using something like:

```
BBOX(the_geom, -90, 40, -60, 45) AND name like 'xxx'
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use longitude values above 90 and below -90 in examples so that the order of the coords is obvious at a glance.